# big ssh problem

Tags: ssh

I generated SSH keys in a temporary file, exported the public one to Launchpad, removed.

I regenerated SSH keys, exported the public one to Launchpad, run `bzr branch lp:bzr-colo ~/.bazaar/plugins/colo`, got an error message, removed the keys.

I regenerated SSH keys, exported the public one to Launchpad, run `bzr branch lp:bzr-colo ~/.bazaar/plugins/colo`, got an error message.

I don't know the first error message. The second is:

```
bzr branch lp:bzr-colo ~/.bazaar/plugins/colo
The authenticity of host 'bazaar.launchpad.net (91.189.90.11)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 9d:38:3a:63:b1:d5:6f:c4:44:67:53:49:2e:ee:fc:89.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'bazaar.launchpad.net,91.189.90.11' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
Permission denied (publickey).
bzr: ERROR: Connection closed: Unexpected end of message. Please check connectivity and permissions, and report a bug if problems persist.
```

I don't know when I run `launchpad-login deltrem1984`.

Google has many error messages containing the same IP and RSA key fingerprint and one of them says:

"This suggests you're trying to use bzr+ssh, but the key you are using
isn't recorded in Launchpad.

You can add as many keys to Launchpad as you like. I can see you already
have one key uploaded there; are you using a different computer, or did
you regenerate your SSH key?"

I didn't export the first key to Launchpad, but the second and third I did. I'm using the same computer, but I regenerated my SSH key - twice.

UPDATE:

I had missed a Google search result! It says ssh-add solves the problem! I'm going to try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important part is "Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.". Either use `ssh-add` to add the key to the agent, or disable use of the agent via `SSH_AUTH_SOCK= bzr ...`.

Comment: I run `ssh-add --help` and added something I didn't want. Should I run `ssh-remove --help`?

Comment: No. `ssh-add -d`